# On what stages can I farm Lesser (**) Ice Orbs?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Other than the appropriate weekly event, which stages offer the best drop rate for Lesser Ice Orbs?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make a more general question to ask for the stage(s) for each type of orb rather than one per type?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau No, because there's some 50 different types of orbs, and a giant spreadsheet isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: A mods question being (presumably automatically) "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content". I think the Stack Exchange software needs to learn some lessons, LessPop.

Comment: @TZHX No, the site is doing its job.  If I were to post two nearly identical questions back to back, I'd expect the site to flag one of my questions, too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have obtained lesser ice orbs from Abandoned Mineshaft (VI) and South Figaro Cave (VI).